# Count occurrences in excel list with list of 400+ different items

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I have a list of about 5K lines that I want to count occurrences for each item.

There are about 300 - 400 different items within this list.

Instead of typing up 300+ unique formulas looking like

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5000,"A")
=COUNTIF(A1:A5000,"B")
=COUNTIF(A1:A5000,"C")
=COUNTIF(A1:A5000,"D")
=COUNTIF(A1:A5000,"E")
ETC to 300...
```

, is there a way I could accomplish this goal with some sort of enhanced formula?

Below is a list example that I borrowed from a previous posted question because it demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish however in my case I have 300 to 400 different items not just A, B, C, D, & E :

"I have a list of items that looks like this:"

```
A
B
C
A
A
B
D
E
A
```

"Now I want to count the number of occurrences of each item. The result should look like this:"

```
A 4
B 2
C 1
D 1
E 1
```

Credit to RoflcoptrException for posting the original question.

Comment: Use a Pivot Table.  See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845977/excel-how-summarize-values-in/58846156#58846156)

Answer (score 0):

*Rather than a formula, I would like to suggest the fastest method, a `VBA Macro` to count the occurrence of various items.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- To create unique list of items to be counted, the array (CSE) formula in cell `C68`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$68:$A$78, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$67:C67, $A$68:$A$78), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Either press **Alt+F11** or **R**ight click sheet TAB and hit **V**iew Code.
- At VB editor window from **I**nsert command click **M**odule.
- **C**opy & **P**aste this code.

  ```
  Public Function CountString(SearchFor As String, InRange As Range) As Long

    Dim wbcs As Long, rng As Range, addr As String
     For Each s In Worksheets

  addr = InRange.Address
  Set rng = s.Range(addr)

  wbcs = wbcs + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "*" & SearchFor & "*")
   Next s
   CountString = wbcs

   End Function
  ```
- Save Workbook as Macro Enabled (.xlsm).
- Enter this formula in cell `D68`, fill down:

`=CountString($C68,A$68:A$78)`

- *To count the occurrence in multiple columns, you may use formula like this.*

`=CountString($C68,A:C)`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to export the values to a text file, say `f.txt`,
and run the following `.bat` script in the same folder:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Accumulate each occurrence in its corresponding array element
for /F %%a in (f.txt) do set /A "[%%a]+=1"

rem Show the result
for /F %%a in ('set [') do echo %%a
```

Running it on your sample data returns:

[image]